# Send simple text message to wechat user from server side

Tags: c#, sdk, wechat

I have wechat app on Android, in Settings->MyAccount I set WeChat ID "**my-wechat-unical-id**".

In WebForms project I add [WeChat.SDK 1.0.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WeChat.SDK/)

now I obtain ACCESS_TOKEN like this:

https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/token?grant_type=client_credential&appid=my_appid&secret=my_secret

How I can to send simple message to '**my-wechat-unical-id**' if this person is not my follower, can I send to him some message or notification in wechat?